# ReportServer connection from ReportViewer control in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a report on a report server

> > http://reportingservicedev.mydomain.com/Reports" with the following folder structure:
> >     Apay/Dev/APayReports

My report name is TestReport.

I have a ReportViewer control with the following configuration:

- Processing Mode is Remote
- ReportServerUrl is

  > "http://reportingservicedev.mydomain.com/Reports/"
- Report Path is

  > "/Apay/Dev/APayReports/TestReport"

The resolved Url would be

> http://reportingservicedev.mydomain.com/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fAPay%2fDev%2fAPayReports%2fTestReport

When I run, I am using Administrator mode of Visual Studio with the same credentials as when I connect manually on the ReportServer.  I get error 404:

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Can anyone see what I have set incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. My settings were correct. Turns out I need to set the ReportServerCredentials on the control's ServerReport.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c65abca7-0fdb-40fb-aabe-718f63377a55/set-credentials-for-reportviewer was a great help.